# How to augment a skip list such that we can extract max value of a specific segment of the skiplist efficiently? [Skiplist not sorted by value]

Tags: data-structures, skip-lists

i have a problem im struggling with.

I have a skiplist with elements:

`element = (date,value)`

The dates are the key's of the skiplist,and hence,the skiplist is sorted by date.
How can i augment the skiplist such that the function

`Max(d1,d2) -> returns largest value between dates d1 and d2`

is most efficient.
The values are integers.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to iterate over each item from `d1` to `d2` and select the maximum item. Because the skip list is ordered by date, you cannot assume anything about the order of values: they might as well be randomly ordered. So you'll have to look at each one.

So it's O(log n) (on average: this is a skip list, after all) to find `d1`, and then it's O(range) to find the maximum element, where `range` is the number of items between `d1` and `d2`, inclusive.

How you'd implement this is to add a function to the skip list that will allow you to iterate the list starting at an arbitrary element. You almost certainly already have a function that will iterate over the entire list in order, so all you have to do is create a function that will iterate over a range of keys (i.e. from a start key to an end key).